# Why is partition key column missing from DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a job which loads a DataFrame object and then saves the data to parquet format using the DataFrame `partitionBy` method. Then I publish the paths created so a subsequent job can use the output. The paths in the output would look like this:

```
/ptest/_SUCCESS
/ptest/id=0
/ptest/id=0/part-00000-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
/ptest/id=0/part-00001-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
/ptest/id=0/part-00002-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
/ptest/id=1
/ptest/id=1/part-00003-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
/ptest/id=1/part-00004-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
/ptest/id=1/part-00005-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
/ptest/id=3
/ptest/id=3/part-00006-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
/ptest/id=3/part-00007-942fb247-1fe4-4147-a41a-bc688f932862.snappy.parquet
```

When I receive new data it is appended to the dataset. The paths are published so jobs which depend on the data can just process the new data.

Here's a simplified example of the code:

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1,"A"), (0,1,"B"), (0,2,"C"), (1,2,"D"), (1,10,"E"), (1,20,"F"), (3,18,"G"), (3,18,"H"), (3,18,"I")])
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score","letter"])
>>> df.show()
+---+-----+------+
| id|score|letter|
+---+-----+------+
|  0|    1|     A|
|  0|    1|     B|
|  0|    2|     C|
|  1|    2|     D|
|  1|   10|     E|
|  1|   20|     F|
|  3|   18|     G|
|  3|   18|     H|
|  3|   18|     I|
+---+-----+------+
>>> df.write.partitionBy("id").format("parquet").save("hdfs://localhost:9000/ptest")
```

The problem is when another job tries to read the file using the published paths:

```
>>> df2 = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(df2.schema).load("hdfs://localhost:9000/ptest/id=0/")
>>> df2.show()
+-----+------+
|score|letter|
+-----+------+
|    1|     A|
|    1|     B|
|    2|     C|
+-----+------+
```

As you can see the partition key is missing from the loaded dataset. If I were to publish a schema that jobs could use I can load the file using the schema. The file loads and the partition key exists, but the values are null:

```
>>> df2 = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(df.schema).load("hdfs://localhost:9000/ptest/id=0/")
>>> df2.show()
+----+-----+------+
|  id|score|letter|
+----+-----+------+
|null|    1|     A|
|null|    1|     B|
|null|    2|     C|
+----+-----+------+
```

Is there a way to make sure the partition keys are stored w/in the parquet data? I don't want to require other processes to parse the paths to get the keys.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case like this you should provide `basePath` `option`:

```
(spark.read
    .format("parquet")
    .option("basePath", "hdfs://localhost:9000/ptest/")
    .load("hdfs://localhost:9000/ptest/id=0/"))
```

which points to the root directory of your data.

With `basePath` `DataFrameReader` will be aware of the partitioning and adjust schema accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is loading specific partition, which it looks like from `load("hdfs://localhost:9000/ptest/id=0/")` path, that application can tweak code to replace null with partition column value

```
part = 0 # partition to load 
df2 =spark.read.format("parquet")\
               .schema(df.schema)\
               .load("ptest/id="+str(part)).fillna(part,["id"])
```

That way, the output will be -

```
+---+-----+------+
| id|score|letter|
+---+-----+------+
|  0|    1|     A|
|  0|    1|     B|
|  0|    2|     C|
+---+-----+------+
```

Comment: The other application only has the full, specific partition because I am publishing the paths (eg. `hdfs://localhost:9000/ptest/id=0/`). It has no knowledge of what the path means or how it's constructed. In order for this solution to work the application must parse the path to extract the value. I'm hoping to avoid this.

Comment: `DataFrameWriter` doesnt have `schema` option so specifying custom schema is out of door. Have you thought of duplicating partition column? one for actual partitioning and duplicate one for other application to consume without having to parse path?

Comment: Thought about it. I may look at that as a potential solution. Or I may change the way I'm publishing the paths to provide knowledge about the partitions and the partition key values